# Keras Dropout Layer Model Predict

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, keras-layer, dropout

The dropout layer is only supposed to be used during the training of the model, not during testing.

If I have a dropout layer in my Keras sequential model, do I need to do something to remove or silence it before I do `model.predict()`?

Answer (score 5):

> No, you don't need to silence it or remove it. Keras automatically
>   takes care of it.

It is clearly mentioned in the [documentation](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#why-is-the-training-loss-much-higher-than-the-testing-loss). A Keras model has two modes:

1. training
2. testing

Regularization mechanisms, such as Dropout and L1/L2 weight regularization, are turned off at testing time.

*Note:* Also, Batch Normalization is a much-preferred technique for regularization, in my opinion, as compared to Dropout. Consider using it.

Comment: Is it same case in Functional API?